# How to configure Https in .net core to send status code description

Tags: .net-core, https, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, http-status-codes

When using  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in startup.cs and https link,
The Response doesn't contain status code description

[Error status code when using https image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq1re.png)

but when  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`  is removed  from startup.cs  and using http link,
The Response contains status code along with description

[Required response got using http image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Halcc.png)

**How to configure https or .Net Core to send status code description ?**

I'm using .NetCore 3.1

statup.cs

```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "BAIM");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

and controller method

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Need the response with error code and description
thanks a lot in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of sending status code in response, i am giving example of a catch block when an exception is thrown

```
          catch (Exception ex)
               {
               Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();


                result["message"] = ex.Message;
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in Get By ID  template");

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, result);

            }
```

Comment: Hello,  Even with this change i got the same response.
the problem is the response has the status code as 400 or 500 etc but the response did not contain status code description while using https.
please check the links in the above question for response image in http vs https